# Google sheets & google analytics authentication

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics

I'm trying to use the real-time-data export for google analytics in google sheets scripts.
However my google analytics api/ developer console is under a different account as my google sheets account.

I specify the project my google sheets script should use in the following line:

```
var ana = Analytics.Data.Realtime.get('ga:xxxxxxxxx','rt:activeUsers, rt:source', {'dimensions' : 'rt:source,rt:medium'});
```

However this throws the error:

> Access Not Configured. Google Analytics API has not been used in project 1046300490979 before or it is disabled.

When i open up this error and click the link provided it sends me to a different project then the project id i specify in the line of code above.

How would i go about getting google analytics data through the API of a different account?

P.S.: I have followed the following guide to set up my google sheets script: https://www.tatvic.com/blog/google-analytics-real-time-data-in-google-sheet/

EDIT: I found out that you can change the project connected to your script.
However after doing so i am getting the following error:

> User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile. (regel 3, bestand 'Code')

In the developer console i have access to everything.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i was using the wrong id's so i'll elaborate a little on where to get what id's in the tutorial above.

Under Resources -> Cloud Platform-project you have to link your script to your google developer console.
You can find this id by going to your developer console, selecting the project connected to your google analytics account. There should be a projectID under Projectinformation
[image: project id]

In the following line:

```
var ana = Analytics.Data.Realtime.get('ga:xxxxxxx', 'rt:activeUsers', {'dimensions' : 'rt:source,rt:medium'});
```

xxxxxxx should be replaced by your google analytics project id, open your google analytics and look at the URL it should be all numbers behind the p.
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/report-home/a75228945w113577272p**128654983**